# What are Pro and Cons of using Lithium batteries over LiPo batteries for quadcopters

Tags: lipo-batteries, battery-cell

I heard that some people combine some Panasonic 18650 (3400mah 3.7V) lithium batteries to make a battery for their drones, I was wondering of the advantages and disadvantages of using this type of set up as opposed to an off the shelf LiPo Battery

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/242/alternatives-to-lipo-batteries