# Which battery do I need for my drone?

Tags: batteries, propellers

I am totally new to the drone space and I recently acquired a hand-me-down drone without a battery.

It has a XT60 male connector type with 4 motors (DL2205 KV=2300).[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Sobhi, welcome to Drones.SE! Could you please tell us more about the hardware on your drone? Like the model of the flight controller, ESCs, etc. of any parts on it. It's not really possible for us to help without some more information.

Comment: Sobhi, even if you don't know anything about the other hardware on your drone, taking a picture of the whole drone instead of just the motor should allow us to give you a good estimate of the necessary battery.

Comment: Based upon feedback, I’ve updated my original thread with additional pictures.

Answer (score 1):

For this drone, a 3s 1500mAh-2200mAh LiPo battery *should work*. ([example 1](https://www.getfpv.com/lumenier-1500mah-3s-45c-lipo-battery.html))([example 2](https://www.racedayquads.com/collections/3s-batteries/products/rdq-series-2200mah-3s-75c-fpv-drone-battery-xt60)) I'm not completely certain that this will be the right battery, but it is extremely likely that this will work, because it would make sense with the KV of the motors.

There are several things to understand when it comes to choosing a good battery and I'll simplify a few of those things below:

1. Voltage: Voltage is measured in V (volts). The voltage is determined by the number of battery cells connected in series. So 3s = 11.1V and 4s = 14.8V. For your drone I would recommend 3s because the ESC may not be able to handle a higher voltage.
2. Capacity: Capacity is measured in mAh (milliamp hour). More capacity means more power that can be used by the drone, but also heavier. It's best to balance this so that you have enough power for a decently long flight but not so heavy that the drone can't fly. For the size of that drone, 1300mAh - 2200mAh should work well.
3. Type: Most drones use LiPo batteries. LiPo batteries are used because of their great power to weight ratio. LiPo would be the best for your drone. There are, however, [alternatives](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/242/alternatives-to-lipo-batteries).

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. It’s greatly appreciated and helpful.